# create react app with older version node js

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use Create React App but getting an error that it requires Node 14 or higher. My node version is Node 13.14.0 and there's no way for me to update the Node version since it's a work machine. Is there any way to run an older version of Create React App to work with my older Node version?